# CakePHP retrieve data, associate models, containable behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-2.3

I can't seem to figure out how the containable behavior works, or how to retrieve the data from (and based) on associated models.

I need to put the following MySQL query in the cakephp find('all') function, I know i can use the query builder for the sql syntax but I want to use find function and want to figure out how it works.

```
SELECT events.id, events.name FROM events, user_roles
WHERE user_roles.event_id = events.id
AND user_roles.user_id = 1
```

The idea is simple, in the user_roles the user_id, role_id and event_id are stored. Now I want to retrieve all events for a certain user (here user_id = 1). I tried some variations on the following:

```
$data = $this->Event->find('all',array(
            'contain' => array(
                'UserRole' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'UserRole.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

But this keeps returning all events. What I want is an array like (or any other result with the same associated data):

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [Event] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Event Name'
        ),
        [UserRole] => array(
            'role_id' => 2,
            'event_id'=> 1
        )
    [1] => array(
        .... etc ...
)
```

The following models and associations are defined

```
class Event extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'UserRole' => array(
            'className' => 'UserRole',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'dependent' => false,
        )
    )
)

class UserRole extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
       'Event' => array(
            'className' => 'Event',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id'
        ),
    )
)
```

So how does it work ;).

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I've set in AppModel.php:

```
public $recursive = -1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Containable finds the associated records for the original query.  What you are doing is a `find('all')` on your `Event` model with absolutely no conditions, so it **will** return all Events.

Then Containable will retrieve all the `UserRole` records that are for the given `user_id` and are also associated to the `Event` by the `event_id`

If you want to only retrieve events for the given user, you could do it one of two ways

Via the Event->UserRole association and chained models:

```
$data = $this->Event->UserRole->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('UserRole.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
    'contain' => array('Event')
));

$events = $data['Event'];
```

or

Via your current code and then using the [`Hash::extract`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html) method to get the Events that match. (`Hash` is a CakePHP core class)

```
$events = Hash::extract('/UserRole[user_id='.$this->Auth->user('id').']/..', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried some version on your first solution, but got the famous column not found error. One aditional question, using Event->UserRole says, find the Events, that have an association with the UserRole model, if I understand the syntax correctly?

Comment: No the `Event->UserRole` is a way of calling methods on a model via the relationships set up in the class, rather than having to instantiate it first.  It doesn't apply any specific filtering to your results, just gives you access to that models methods.